# why data is not inserting to database?

Tags: php

i am using php for inserting data in in mysql database. i am new to php and also mysql please help

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>create menu</title>
</head>
<h1 align="center">create menu</h1>
<h2 align="center">Dont create more than 7 menu</h2><br/><br/>
<form method="post">
    <table border="2px" width="500px">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" align="center">create menu</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">menu name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="menu"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="create"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("coupons");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $menu=$_POST['menu'];
    $query = "insert into menu(item) values ('$menu')";
    if(mysql_query($query)){
        echo "<h1 align='center'>DATA INSERTED</h1>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<h1>data not inserted</h1>";
    } 
}
?>
```

where am i wrong please help data is not inserting to database

Comment: first, you should look at sql injection, your code isn't safe

Comment: You ask us why, I tell you that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated in PHP5 and removed in PHP7. Upgrade  your code and start using prepared statements.

Comment: mysql is deprecated => use pdo or mysqli

Answer (score 1):

First thing which version of php you are using, because `mysql_connect()` is not supported in newer version of php.
If your php version doesn't support this function you should get error on submit.

so i suggest you to replace mysql_xxx with mysqli_xxx (as you can see here [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php))

replace these 2  lines

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("coupons");
```

with these lines of code

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($con,"coupons");
```

And

update if condition with this mysqli_xxx() as

```
if(mysqli_query($query))
```

For more detail please read [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this, for your php code

`<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "coupons";

try{

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $query=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO menu( item) VALUES( :menu)");
    $query->bindParam(':menu',$menu);
    $menu=$_POST['menu'];

    $query->execute();


    echo "<h1 align='center'>DATA INSERTED</h1>";
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
    // roll back the transaction if something failed
    $conn->rollback();
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    echo "<h1>data not inserted</h1>";
        }

    $conn = null;
    ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working absolutely fine. I tried it on my system. Check the screenshot -

#### HTML form submission result -

[image]

#### Value in database -

[image]

### Possible errors on your system -

> - MySql is not running.
> - Database name is incorrect
> - You have not provided the password